# How to add a class and other HTML attributes on the same object on template Jinja2?

Tags: html, css, templates, flask, jinja2

Considering this partial HTML code below:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <label>IVA</label>
    </td>
    <td>
        {{form.iva(class="form-control")}}
        {% if form.iva.errors %}<span class="error">{{';'.join(form.iva.errors)}}</span>{%endif%}
    </td>
</tr>
```

And this partial python code (Flask/Wtforms):

```
iva = SelectField(u"IVA", [validators.Required()], choices=[])
```

Besides of  set the class "form-control" I would like to add some more style but without change the class, in other words, just add some more style in this specific object, eg: width: 150px;

So, How I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rendering fields adding some keywords arguments which will be injected as html attributes like **style**, **placeholder**, **autocomplete**, etc:

```
<tr>
<td><label>IVA</label></td>
<td>
  {{form.iva(class="form-control",style="min-width: 150px; max-width: 200px;")}}
  {% if form.iva.errors %}<span class="error">{{';'.join(form.iva.errors)}}</span>{%endif%}
</td>
</tr>
```

See more information in the [official documentation](http://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/crash_course.html#rendering-fields)